# Image effect console error

Tags: unity, image-effects

I have imported image effects from asset store in my project. 
When imported, I've got 5 error messages :

```
Assets/Standard Assets/Effects/TonemappingColorGrading/Editor/TonemappingColorGradingEditor.cs(370,134): warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.TextureImporterFormat.AutomaticTruecolor' is obsolete: `Use textureCompression property instead'
```

What to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the TonemappingColorGradingEditor.cs script. And on line number 370, Replace TextureImporterFormat.AutomaticTruecolor with TextureImporterCompression.Uncompressed.

Comment: Thank you. How come this is not set by default ?

Comment: You would have updated your game engine, but not the standard assets, I guess